# Error when trying to send a mail to a list of email addresses (which has an invalid email Id)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

Here is the scenario:

I have a list of email addresses to which I have to send a MimeMessage.
The list sometimes might contain invalid email addresses which needs to be handled.

I’m doing something like this:

```
MimeMessagePreparator preparator = mimeMessage -> {
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    helper.setTo(recepientsCommaSeparated.split(","));
    helper.setCc(recepientsCcCommaSeparated.split(","));
    helper.setSubject(map.get(SUBJECT_FIELD));
    helper.setText(map.get(CONTENT_FIELD), true);
};
try {
    this.mailSender.send(preparator);
} catch (MailException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This doesn’t send the email to valid emailAddresses and fails the entire call.
I’m expecting something where valid emailAddresses receive the email and invalid email Addresses can be caught and handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set property `mail.smtp.sendpartial` to true.

> If set to true, and a message has some valid and some invalid addresses, send the message anyway, reporting the partial failure with a SendFailedException.

Detailed documentation [Here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html)

Comment: Totally overlooked it!